# Eclipse EGit Command Line

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I recently installed Git for Eclipse (EGit) and I have used some basic functions by right-click -> Team -> Add/Commit/Remove/Exclude/etc.

However, I would like to use some of the more complicated features of git, and command-line syntaxes. Is there a way to do this in Eclipse or set up EGit in command line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not provided by EGit itself, but there are multiple options:

- A generic command shell, see [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25734655/305973)
- [Gonsole plugin](http://rherrmann.github.io/gonsole/), which provides some command completion and integration with EGit

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can get direct access to a command prompt for egit.  However, you could use one of the many plugins that create a command shell at a particular folder, so you can just type the git command you want.  One of those is the [PathTools](https://code.google.com/p/pathtools/) plugin, which also lets you record specific command lines you can run on a shell.